# C++ Compilation error:- multiple definition of `main' using Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have three files with `Trigger.cpp` , `Trigger.h` and `corchainf.cpp` from which `corchainf.cpp` has `main()` function. Now when I am compiling these using make command I get the following error:-

```
corchainf.o: In function `main':
corchainf.cpp:(.text+0x40): multiple definition of `main'


corchainf.o:corchainf.cpp:(.text+0x40): first defined here

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [corchainf] Error 1
```

I am suspecting the error is in Makefile because everything else i have checked so this is the makefile
[makefile image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwmgD.png)
[makefile image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRL52.png)

Can anyone suggest where in makefile is the main() function which is in corchainf.cpp ; is being called multiple times??

Edit:- Got the solution to problem. in makefile the corchainf.cpp which had main function was bieng called two times by $(MAINO) and $(OBJS) ; so removed $(MAINO) and VOILA!!! it worked. Thanks everyone for answering.

Comment: Show code! Don't show images.

Comment: All information needed to solve the problem should be contained in the question itself. Furthermore, it is considered good style to show your progress/attempts so far. Other than that, welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: it says multiple definition of main. So check your corchainf.cpp file, where you have multiple definition of main.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Ya i figured out the problem. Also i dont know ; i am not able to paste the code. If i want to copy the whole code and paste it here using the 'Code' option ; its only pasting the first line as code and then all others as plain text ; thats why used images. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `corchainf.o` is being included twice in your recipe for `$(MAIN)`.  Once in `$(OBJS)`, and once in `$(MAINO)`.

And please, as commenters have mentioned, just paste the code into the question.  Don't link images.

Comment: @VAIBHAV When pasting code, make sure every line is indented by four spaces. That way the whole thing will be formatted correctly.